# Bluetooth randomly disabled while actively using bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth

The bluetooth on my MacBook randomly turns off multiples times throughout the day, even when I am actively using my wireless keyboard and mouse. This issue has persisted for months.

As I am typing or clicking, my keyboard and mouse suddenly become unresponsive. When I look up in the menu bar, the bluetooth icon is grayed out with a diagonal line through it.

I then have to reach over to my laptop trackpad and use it to click the bluetooth icon and click the toggle to re-enable bluetooth.

Once I do that, my devices reconnect and I can use them again.

I've also had intermittent issues using bluetooth on the login screen. Sometimes it's enabled, sometimes not, sometimes it's enabled for a few seconds and then becomes disabled.

It's so inconsistent that I always use my laptop keyboard and trackpad to log in, ensure bluetooth is on, and then start using my wireless keyboard and mouse.

---

Device Info:

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020)
- Ventura 13.4.1

These are the bluetooth devices I'm trying to use:

- [Logitech MX Keys Mini Wireless Keyboard](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/keyboards/mx-keys-mini.920-010388.html)
- [Logitech MX Anywhere 3 Wireless Mouse](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/mice/mx-anywhere-3s.910-006926.html)

---

Things I've tried:

- rebooting
- updating to the latest version of my operating system
- turning my mouse and keyboard off and back on
- forgetting all my bluetooth devices
- reconnecting only my bluetooth keyboard and mouse
- using `sudo pkill bluetooth` to reset bluetooth
- using `sudo pkill bluetoothd` to reset bluetooth
- using `Opt-Cmd-P-R` to reset NVRAM
- ensuring my bluetooth devices are fully charged
- ensuring the Logi Options+ app is NOT installed

Comment: What research and troubleshooting have you done to fix the problem?

Comment: Mac model and version of macOS?  Just to be certain, you’re not using a third party adapter, are you?  Have you tried booting in Safe Mode (plug in a USB keyboard in case the BT connection is lost)

Comment: Just the model name and year is sufficient.  We don’t need a huge image where a single line of text will work.   Now, when booting (from power off) can you use the keyboard to go into the  boot manager (Hold `Opt`) or into Recovery (`Cmd-R`)?

Comment: Here is where i recommend an NVRAM reset. With a USB keyboard, press `Opt-Cmd-P-R` during power up. Hold for 20 to 30 seconds.  Then boot normally and make sure BT is enabled.